# Column header wrapping when using Angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I have upgraded my AngularJS SPA application from `ng-grid v2.0.7` to `ui-grid v3` and my column headers no longer wrap around. My column headers are now single lined and show an ellipsis `...` when the column header doesn't fit.

Has this feature been removed or is had it been superseded by a different method?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe I have found a way of wrapping text in the header columns by overriding the `ui-grid-cell-contents` CSS class.

```
.ui-grid-header-cell .ui-grid-cell-contents {
     height: 48px;
     white-space: normal;
     -ms-text-overflow: clip;
     -o-text-overflow: clip;
     text-overflow: clip;
     overflow: visible;
}
```

Adding this to my site.css I find the column names are now wrapping onto the next line as expected.

Works in Chrome (v41) and Firefox (v35).

Comment: Is there a way to wrap cells and height is automatic, such that no value will be clipped?

Comment: `height: auto !important;` To make the height of the header automatic
    `font-size: 11px;`  Reduce font size

Comment: An improved version, http://plnkr.co/edit/BZFcGHB7lY120bEOnDyn?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

I added the following css to get mine to work. The line height auto adjusts when depending on the number of lines needed. When scrolling horizontally, it will change to number of lines based on what is visible.

```
.ui-grid-header-cell-label {
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:initial;
}
```