# adding a new line in column header of angular ui-grid

Tags: html, angularjs, web, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to add new row to the column header in ui-grid but not finding a way to achieve this. Tried searching the documentation as well as the google a lot but of no use. Can any one please help me in this regard.

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkbGvLe9myc3nB5riaAE?p=preview

```
{name: 'name', displayName: 'Name \n(editable)' },
```

I am trying to add new line here between name and editable.

Also is it possible to span the column in `ui-grid` (I should be able to export the data also in same format.. according to the already bug opened, it is not possible but has anyone tried it?)

Comment: looks like your looking for something like this right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730621/column-header-wrapping-when-using-angular-ui-grid

Comment: Ya..since I am using ui-grid CDN, so I dont want to create my styling now.. anyway..I got answer now from @shagrin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use headerCellTemplate, the simplest would be:

```
{ name: 'name', headerCellTemplate: '<div class="">Name <br>(editable)</div>' },
```

[Here is the link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/src/templates/ui-grid/uiGridHeaderCell.html) to full header cell template from ui-grid, you can customize it.